# How i can give to user test build for Windows Phone 7 like an iOS? Is here exists UDIDs or some else?

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing

i'm new in Windows Phone Dev.

I make some app. How i can give it to another user (tester) like i do it on Apple iOS Dev?

I mean - in iOs i get Device UDID from test user and send him .ipa file with Provision Profile.

Is for Windows exist similar procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- [**Register the device**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) of your tester as a developper device. You can register up to **three** phones for Development. You will then just have to deploy the XAP from Visual Studio.
- Submit your app for a [**Beta distribution**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334585%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). There you will be asked to specify the Windows Live ID email addresses of your beta users. They will be able to download the app via a specific URL.